# decreased by 1/3?

Tags: grammar

9 has been decreased to 6.

Which is/are correct?

a. It was decreased one third.
b. It was decreased by one third.
c. It was decreased two thirds.
d. It was decreased to two thirds.
e. or any other better expresssion.

Comment: Homework? What is your thoughts yourself?

Comment: Such statements are always a hair ambiguous, and some people really have trouble with them, but most idiomatic would be "decreased by one-third".

Comment: Thank you! I thought b and d may be correct. (with hyphen in between)

Comment: I feel that :  a. would mean 9 X 1/3 = 3  (??)

Comment: @DKChun When you "decrease N by X" it means (N - (N * X)). Nine decreased by one-third = (9 - (9 * 1/3)) == (9 - (3)) == _6_. For a real world example with a similar confusion: http://notalwaysright.com/their-math-education-came-at-a-discount/44386

Comment: No hyphens when the amounts are at the end of the sentence, with nothing following. So no hyphens for the above. But if, "It was decreased by one-third 'volume,'" for example, then you do use the hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

A, B and D seem correct. It's decreased ***by*** 1/3 (the amount you subtract), meaning it decreases ***to*** 2/3 (the remainder after subtraction).

Comment: B too then surely.

Comment: Yes. No idea how I missed that. Correcting now.

Comment: E is correct as well.